# Can a tubular tire be reused?

Tags: tire, wheels, cyclocross

I have some knobby cross-specific tubular tires (Challenge Limus 33) mounted on a bike and I want to change them in exchange for slick tires for a period of riding primarily on the pavement.  While they are excellent tires, and have a lot of life left, the road noise is undesirable.

Can these tires be reused after they have been separated from the rim tape and/or glue?

Comment: Watch for a used tubular wheelset.  You get CX racers that trade up and sell nice used stuff cheap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse them.

Just be careful removing the old ones, clean them up and then swap on the new ones.